# Cosine similarity between a vector and a mean of vectors/a sum of vectors

Tags: vectors, data-mining

I am trying to understand how cosine similarity works when applied to two vectors: considering vectors $u$ and $v$, their cosine similarity is computed as follows:

$cos(u,v)$ = $\frac{u\cdot v}{||u||*||v||}$

so we divide the dot product of the two vectors by the product of their norms.
While reading, I stumbled in the following proposition:

> vector sum and vector average are equivalent under cosine similarity,
> because the cosine is only sensitive to vector direction and not to
> vector length.

The idea is to compare by cosine similarity a vector $u$ to two other vectors $x$ and $y$, where $x$ is obtained by summing a list of vectors $v1,...,vn$ and $y$ is obtained by averaging that same list $v1,...,vn$.

In this case, should $cos(u,x) = cos(u,y)$ ?

Comment: Yes.  The two cosines will be equal, because $y$ is just a scaled copy of $x$, i.e. $y = \alpha x$ where $\alpha \gt 0 $.